# How to create custom VS Code Intellisense documentation for a Python library

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am in the process of creating custom Python libraries with simple functions I use in other projects. My main IDE for using Python is Visual Studio Code, and I find its Python Intellisense very useful.

Is there a way to write or include my own custom documentation for my libraries that will show up in VS Code Intellisense?

Comment: VS Code supports Python docstrings, which are what most libraries use for documentation. What issue do you have with those?

Comment: No issue - I just didn’t know exactly where to start and didn’t have any luck searching for things like “how to create custom python documentation for vs code”. A quick google search for Python docstrings told me everything I need to know. Thank you, UnholySheep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UnholySheep mentioned above, VS Code supports Python docstrings. Including these in my code provided the desired result.

Comment: I will mark it as ‘answered’ as soon as I can. Still have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer. Thanks! =)