# How to customize Python Intellisense documentation format in Vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

This is the same that Paul wanted to do in [Create Custom VS Code Intellisense Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003094)

The thing is that I am working in quite big project that **doesn't** use the standard Python docstring (`"""documentation"""`), instead they use the following format:

```py
# DESCRIPTION:
#   Adds two numbers
# PARAMETERS:
#   a - first number to add
#   b - second number to add
# RETURNS:
#   Sum of a and b
def add(a, b):
  return a + b
```

I would like that Intellisense shows me this documentation whenever I hover over the add function wherever it is used, but since the project doesn't use docstrings this doesn't happens.

Comment: You should use standard docstring because: Less `#`, standard, ALL IDEs detect docstring by `""" """`.

Comment: The problem is that the code base is too big to change all of the files to the standard docstring.

Comment: By the way, Java Intellisense supports a similar type of documentation, maybe this is not customizable but I don't know

Comment: The reason you should use `""" """` is other can also use IntelliSense with it.

Comment: I think the above statement is very clear. Python extension can only be realized by using standard docstring """ """.